# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) crash in C++

Tags: c++, qt, assertion

I have a Qt GUI program, inside it I could click a button to load/unload many dock widgets.
I have the problem that when I click the button to load/unload dock widgets, the programm crash with saying that

```
Debug Assertion Failed, Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

It doesn't happen every time. (Actually very rare to happen.)
And when I check the Windows's event log, it says the application hang with a cross thread dead lock.
But most people online said that the _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) means a memory error.
I just don't what's going on...

It is a very big program by someone else and the bug happens very rarely...
What I could do now to locate the bug?

EDIT:
Hi, I have got the crash dump file, and I have seen that my program stop at a worker thread with the call stack: >  ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20()  + 0x15 bytes
How could I trace back to the source code that the program actually stop?

Comment: _"What I could do now to locate the bug?"_ - Start by using a debugger.

Comment: I used the default debugger comes with the vc++2010, but the bug just won't come out...Every thing goes fine and end smoothly. What could I do to force the bug to come out?

Comment: You make it sound like some sort of vermin.  Maybe a lurcher or ferret would help?

Comment: Could you at least post the relevant (and as short as possible) code related to the problem?

Comment: Sorry but there are thousands of lines of codes... As long as I could figure out the where is the possible buggy part, I will post it.

Comment: @Nyaruko When that dialog pops up, *do not close it*.  Attach the debugger to the process that is being run and view the call stack.

Comment: Thanks, I know this...But the problem is I have tried several hours, and the bug just won't come out again...

Comment: Make sure you are using a Qt build for your compiler. It is not safe to use Qt that was built with a different version of Visual Studio. It is also not safe to mix debug and release in the same application.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "not safe to mix debug and release in the same application?"

Comment: You can not have debug dlls in a release application or release dlls in a debug application (unless the offending dll isolates the allocations and deallocations). Both cases you will have 2 independent heaps where you can not allocate memory in 1 heap and free it in a second heap. Freeing memory in a different heap will cause heap corruption and random crashes caused by the corrupt heaps.

Answer (score 2):

That usually means you're trying to access an illegal memory block inside an std container.

To debug this properly, just look at the stack in the `Call Stack` window, look up the stack until you get to your code, and see why the value is invalid.

Comment: Sorry but when I did this in the debugger, every thing seems totally right? So I have to repeat and repeat until the bug happens again?

Comment: @Nyaruko Basically yes, or you could attach the process to the debugger when it happens. In Visual Studio see: Debug -> Attach to process. Then you can just pause it and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to describe it, but briefly, here is what you should do:

Install Application Verifier and run it.

<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, select your executable.

Deselect all tests in the right pane, select only Basic->Heaps.

Ensure you have 'Full heap' enabled and 'Traces' enabled (properties via right click on 'Heaps' item).

Save. You may close Application Verifier now.

Launch WinDBG of proper architecture (the same as your app).

<kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>, select your executable.

The program will be stopped on first instruction, run it using <kbd>F5</kbd>

The probability you'll hit the bug will be much higher. You'll also may found memory access issue you were not aware of before. When you hit one of them, the debugger will stop with one of 'Verifier stops' and you'll see the message in console telling you which command you can use to investigate further. Usually you'll be able to see detailed info about the heap using `!heap -p -a <address>`, including allocation and deallocation stacks.

Remember, that Application Verifier checks are enabled even when Application Verifier application is not started. You need to run Application Verifier, disable the checks and press 'Save' to actually disable them.

Hope this will help, at least a bit. Read more about Application Verifier techniques on the Internet.

Comment: It reveals tons of bugs in the original codes which is not by me...sad now... but still thanks.